# How to make UITextView which finish text with dots according to contentSize?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uitextfield

I have a UITextview with dynamic data and i have a size with height let's say 200, how i can crop text in UITextField text to much the height and add "..." to it ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17344735/756941) will help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this text view supposed to be enabled for input?

if yes, then you shouldn't be cropping the text

if no, then you could use a UILabel and change the `numberOfLines` to display, and then set the `lineBreakMode` property to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`

Comment: actually i used UILabel and it works great, my question is not for searching a best decision, it's about UITextView.